# Sounds beautiful, doesn't it

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

So I found this puzzle from an old book of mine with very little instructions. I can't seem to remember the right approach to the solution **BUT** I do remember the final answer, which is 8 letters only.

Can you figure it out?

---

### [image]

**NOTE:** Changed the body due to possible ambiguities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expound on my comment, here's a further partial. Building from trolley's observation that

> the fronts of the squares appear to correspond to playing cards,

I set about listing which cards were present. After doing so I noticed that

> the 10 through Ace are all present, along with all four 2's.

This suggested that the TOP 5 mentioned in (*) are, in fact,

> poker hands, of which a royal flush and four of a kind are the first and third-best, respectively.
>  However, a problem soon arises - distributing the cards into poker hands, one soon runs out of good hands. I initially assumed that the TOP 5 are actually the five best hands, but there is no straight flush besides Royal that can be made from the given cards, not to mention that four of a kind is out of place. If one instead tries to arrange the cards into the five best *possible* hands, one gets the following setup (with cards arranged as in (**)):
>  [image]
>  At this point, no hand higher than a single pair exists, so the division of the final cards is ambiguous barring additional information.

EDIT: The ambiguity noted in the first case is resolved and I've noticed something I missed the first time: a pair of threes.
The *real* grid:

> [image]
>  The position of NORTH seems to indicate that this should be read in alternating columns, like so: **36.1126 NORTH 115.1767 WEST**
>  Inputting this into the search engine of your choice reveals the eight-letter password to be **BELLAGIO**

Nice puzzle!

Comment: Aaah! This is what happens when you didn't realize the 'Royal' part of SF wasn't just a 'cool' name for describing the 10-A type of SF and not considering that as a different type of hand/SF. However, if we consider the four of a kind as 2:nd, then there is only one possible full house (if we consider the remaining cards) with the 3's instead and the rest will follow. But yeah technically it should've been different there too

Comment: Thanks, well done!

Answer (score 3):

An incomplete and possibly wrong answer: Could it be

> Las Vegas?

First, notice that

> in the "front" there are letters C,D,H, and S (no others) paired with the numbers ranged from 2 to 14.

It heavily resembles

> a set of playing cards, with **c**lubs, **d**iamons, **h**earts and **s**pades, ranging from the deuce (2) up to the ace (14). (Side note: an ace is technically a 1.)

So, the task seems to be

> to rearrange the cards in some order to give the answer built from the characters on their backs.

Now, notice that

> the letters on the back side spell out "NORTH" and "WEST", and there are 2 full stops.

So,

> along with the world map on the left, the answer could be indicated as a pair of geographical coordinates, e.g. **xx.xxxxNORTH 1xx.xxxxWEST** (since the latitude cannot be greater than 90, while the longitude can be as high as 180).

Now we can deduce that

> the point lies in the western US (including Alaska/Hawaii) or western Canada.

Now (probably a bit of cheating)

> let's ask a question: *What point in that region is most associated with cards and has 8 letters?*

The answer is obvious:

> It's Las Vegas! (Unfortunately, Erlanger, Kentucky (where most of US-produced playing cards are made) won't work since it lies east of 100W meridian, thus having longitude less than 100.)

Now we can try

> to make some coordinates of a point inside Las Vegas from the provided numbers.

So,

> for example, *36.1166 NORTH 115.1727 WEST* works very well, it is a point in the centre of the city.

But the answer is marked as incomplete because

> the most interesting part - the arrangement of cards in the right order - is omitted (well, I actually have no ideas on how to do so). For the very same reason, the answer can be wrong.

Comment: Nice job working backwards! But still, this is not the answer I had in mind. I'll wait and see until tomorrow if someone can make sense of the front part which will lead to the right combo. If not, i'll give you a hint.

Comment: The existence of rot13(F gra guebhtu sbhegrra naq sbhe gjbf) seems to suggest that the TOP 5 are (cbxre unaqf), except there are no possibilities for (fgenvtug syhfu!)

Comment: @AxiomaticSystem Yes, I've also thought of it, but it didn't yield for me any feasible result.